# Handle deprecated overrides in android

Tags: android, overriding, deprecated

I am updating my Android App to work with the latest version (it was developed with Lollipop). On inspecting the code I see several deprecated methods. Thanks to previous questions I have understood how to handle calls to depercated methods (check for targetSdkVersion > Build.VERSION_CODES.. etc)
However there are several overrodes to deprecated methods. How do I handle this?
for e.g. I use a WebViewClient() in which i override the onReceivedError(..) method

```
@Override
public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
    ...
    super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
}
```

The documentation says tis method was deprecated in API23, and I now need to use `onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error)`

My question is, how do I go about writing the check for the deprecated method? 
Could I simply do:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M) 
@Override
onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error){...}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error){..}
```

Is there any additional check I need?

Comment: You don't have to "handle" deprecations. "Deprecated" code will still work on newer OS versions. Or you would have to rewrite your app every month or two. Because every day they wake up and deprecate something.

Comment: Please edit your question. It is not clear what are you asking. Try to minimize you code and use "Code Snippet" to make it more readable

Comment: True, there are constant changes, but if I am updating the code in my App anyway, isn't it a good idea to put in checks for deprecated methods?

Answer (score 0):

You can check it by similar statement as this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            do some work for LOLLIPOP
        } else {
            do some work for older versions
        }
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I do when I am *calling* a deprecated method.My question is for *overriding* a deprecated method.

Comment: why override when you can use different method for each situation?

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, how do I go about writing the check for the deprecated method?

For callbacks? You don't. If your `minSdkVersion` is high enough, just use the newer callback. Otherwise, just use the older callback. The exception would be if the documentation tells you to do otherwise, perhaps based on `targetSdkVersion`, though I cannot think of any scenarios where this happens.

For backwards compatibility, the old callbacks still work. On newer devices, they automatically "fall back" to using the old callbacks if the newer one is not implemented.